# CSS contextual onclick menu to change z-index when toggled to allow covered space to be interactive

Tags: css

The following mechanism  allows the creation of a drop-down menu that appears only when clicked on as its visibility is being toggled.

```
button + .dd_menu:active,
button:focus + .dd_menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
.ul_dd_menu_lang {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.89); 
  border: 1px solid rgba(169,156,156,0.45);
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
```

This is being placed in a header container

```
#admin-header_container { 
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 40px; 
  top: 0px; 
  z-index: 100;
}
```

where

```
<div id='admin-header_container'>
    <button><%= I18n.locale %></button>
    <nav class='dd_menu'>
      <ul class='ul_dd_menu_lang'>
      <% I18n.available_locales.each do |locale| %>
        <% next if locale == I18n.locale %>
        <li  class='dd_item'><%= link_to locale.to_s, url_for( request.params.merge(locale: locale)), class: 'locale' %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The main container and its content starts below the header, but will slide underneath it upon scrolling

```
#admin-container { 
  width:100%;
  display: table;
  margin-top:60px;
  padding-bottom:60px;
  *zoom:1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
#admin-content{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0 7px 0 7px; 
}
```

However, this means that whatever the height of the `dd_menu`, that height will be inherited by the parent value and 'cover' any contents within that height, rendering objects there unclickable.

[This jsfiddle replicates](https://jsfiddle.net/dvo4/k3saeung/11/) the issue.  A bit tricky to get the inspector to reveal the unordered list as active, but still selecting the `<div class='cell small-2'>`  shows how the parent element has a height of 105, encompassing all `ul` components

Thus the `z-index` is the problem attribute. How can this be handled to have the  admin-content fully interactive?

Comment: Please create working code snippet. Your put us irrelevant HTML and CSS codes.

Comment: it took a while to remove clutter from source....  Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out z-index was not in play, the wrapper class maintains its position.
#admin-header_container {
z-index: 100;
}
However, the trick of toggling visibility was the red herring; the proper way about this was invoking display and toggling that value on `active` class.

```
.dd_menu {
/*     visibility: hidden; */
 display: none;
}
button:focus + .dd_menu {
/*    visibility: visible; */
  display: inline; 
}
button + .dd_menu:active {
/*   visibility: visible;  */ 
   display: inline;
}
```

The jsfiddle reference in question is adjusted to allow to toggle between both instances of pseudo-classes.